SQL Server - Daily Database Restore suddenly taking much longer
We have a daily database restore process which has been running for years without issue.
Essentially we take a database backup from one server and restore that backup on another database server (both MS SQL Server 2019)
Usually this restore process was taking 15mins, however from last week it suddenly jumped to 1 hour, and is consistently taking this amount of time since.
Where can I begin troubleshooting the cause of unexpected extra restore time?
Points to note include:

The size of the backup hasn't grown (infact the size of the database has reduced by a couple of gigs)
There have been no underlying server changes in terms of reducing CPU or RAM etc.
We did start encrypting (TDE) some other databases on the server where we're restoring the backup to, but these were completed one week before we started seeing the increase in restore time.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

For me in the past, these symptoms were a sign of a bad disk. What does your CrystalDiskMark scores show for the disk the backup is being restored from and restored to? (You can add a screenshot of the results to your post.) What type of disks are they?

You'll want to start by getting the wait stats and using those to inform you about where to invest time next.

Have you checked the state of the VLFs? If you log has grown, particularly in small increments, you may have a fragmented log file which affects, among other things, restore performance. Kimberly Tripp has a very good post about this topic: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/transaction-log-vlfs-too-many-or-too-few/

Check if Instant File Initialization is still enabled on the second server
